# Indicating whether a value is in a specified set

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a Google Sheets formula that indicates whether a value (e.g., the contents of `A1`) is in a specified set (e.g., `1, 5, 9`)?

Yes, I could do a `SWITCH(A1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 9, 1, 0)`, but that is overly verbose.

I want something terse like `ISINSET(A1, 1, 5, 9)`.

Comment: Is your data type in A1 numeric or string? And if numeric, is there a definite range of possible values? If so, what is that range? If not, what else can you tell us about the A1 value?

Comment: Each value will be a positive integer from 1 to around 67 or so, or the cell will be empty

Comment: And is the number set to try to match with listed somewhere in your sheet? Or will it only be listed within the formula? (It would be the professional standard in most cases to list the possible match values somewhere, typically in a separate sheet that may be hidden.) But what is your own situation currently regarding this? In addition, will you be trying to process *only one* cell — A1 — or a range of cells? (All of this would be easier if we could simply view a sample spreadsheet that represents the goal in a realistic manner.)

Comment: I could put the numbers in a separate work sheet, but it will probably be easier to just embed them in the formula. There are only around six numbers in the set.

Comment: See edits to my previous comment, particularly: Are you trying to process only A1 for a match, or a number of cells in a range? If the latter, what is the actual range (e.g., B2:B, A2:A100, H3:H)?

Comment: Just a match. Using for conditional formatting

Comment: Ah. In that case, the formula offered by ZygD is the one you want. I see you are fairly new to the site. As you continue to post in the future, keep in mind that details matter, and the volunteer contributors here don't know anything outside of what you post. For instance, this would have gotten to the heart of things faster: "I'm trying to write a conditional formatting formula to see if the number in a single cell matches any of a set of other numbers." (How such a formula would be constructed depends on many factors, as evidenced by my comments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=arrayformula(or(A1={1, 5, 9}))
```

[image]

Comment: That works. Thanks. I'll leave the question open for now, but I'll accept your answer sometime soon assuming no one supplies a more concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one:

`=not( isna( match( A1, { 1, 5, 9 }, 0 ) ) )`